# Please critique error-reporting approach in C

Tags: c, idioms

While working on relatively straightforward C code at work today, I began day-dreaming a little and wrote up the following library for effectively producing error messages. The jury is still out - in my mind, at least - whether this is a more effective approach than simply adapting `perror` with `errno` to your purposes... It doesn't even need to be a "library" at all, rather just a set of macros.

For now, I'm calling the library `elib`:

## elib.h

```
#ifndef _ELIB_H_
#define _ELIB_H_

struct ErrorMap {
    void (*fp);
    int errorCode;
    char * message;
};

#define eperror(...) fprintf(stderr,  ##__VA_ARGS__)
char * getErrorMsg(struct ErrorMap *, void (*fp), int);

#endif /* _ELIB_H_ */
```

## elib.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "elib.h"

char * getErrorMsg(struct ErrorMap * errorMap, void (*fp), int code)
{
    int i;
    // TODO: Replace naive search
    for (i=0; errorMap[i].fp != NULL; i++)
    {
        if (errorMap[i].fp == fp && errorMap[i].errorCode == code)
        {
            return errorMap[i].message;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

## test.c (sample app "xyzlib")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "elib.h"

int xyzlib_openFile(int);
int xyzlib_putStuff(char *);

static struct ErrorMap xyzlib_ErrorMap [] = {
    {xyzlib_openFile, -1, "Argument is less than 3"},
    {xyzlib_putStuff, -1, "Argument is NULL"},
    {xyzlib_putStuff, -2, "Length of argument is 0"},
    {xyzlib_putStuff, -3, "Stuff is too long"},
    {NULL, 0, NULL}
};


int xyzlib_openFile(int fd)
{
    if (fd > 3)
    {
        return (-1);
    }

    // open a file.. or something.

    return 0;
}

int xyzlib_putStuff(char * stuff)
{
    if (stuff == NULL)
    {
        return (-1);
    }

    if (strlen(stuff) == 0)
    {
        return (-2);
    }

    if (strlen(stuff) > 3)
    {
        return (-3);
    }

    // do something ...

    return (0);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int code;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <arg>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    code = xyzlib_putStuff(argv[1]);

    if (code < 0)
    {
        eperror("Error: %s\n", getErrorMsg(xyzlib_ErrorMap, xyzlib_openFile, code));    
    }
}
```

Basically, you define/register the return codes in the ErrorMap table, and if you ever receive an error indication (response value < 0), then the `getErrorMsg` will look through the registered table for the corresponding code and function to get the proper message. I think the value is that for a given library taking this approach to error reporting, error codes can be defined per function (rather than globally) - simplifying management of all the codes.

However, in addition to a small overhead looking up the appropriate message, all C code taking this approach would require every function (that doesn't return non-negative integers) to return `int`s, and then use the first argument to be a pointer to the return value -- Slightly non-idiomatic but commonly used.

Let's say the target market is software for high-reliability embedded devices (but not terribly resource-constrained).

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a symbol table, isn't having a function pointer less useful than having a string form of the function? Granted, finding a way to "export" `__function__` or equivalent outside the function may take some ingenuity.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. One approach is to add a field of the ErrorMap struct to include the string of that function, and then to make sure to create a string for each function in the header file. I've never heard of \__function\__, is that some kind of macro that returns the name of the function it's currently in?

Comment: Looks to me like a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - you sure? (I've never used CodeReview) I'm not using this code verbatim in any project, rather just looking for a discussion of this approach.

Comment: Not really *sure*, but it certainly *sounds* like it to me.

Comment: @B.VB. Or derivative thereof. Look at `<boost/current_function.hpp>`. Cpp is cpp, so there's no C++-isms there to confuse you.

Comment: There's a fundamental tradeoff between global error codes and localized ones.  Localized ones mean that you must always translate errors from one error-space into another one instead of allowing them to percolate up. (There also might not be a direct translation from one error-space to the other.)  Translating error codes across module boundaries often is not too much of a burden, but having to do it *per function* sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: Heh, then this is the real test: If you hopped on a project and they had a routine in place doing something like this, would you be neutral to it or would it make you aggravated and cranky?

Comment: "just looking for a discussion of this approach" -- That's explicitly contrary to SO's purpose -- see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a point in this, sorry. Maybe that's because of how i work with error codes in C. Basically i define error values as a part of the interface of a single module. The error *value* between modules do collide, i.e. i don't care if two modules have the same numerical value for their different error codes. To get strong type-checking for different enums i usually wrap them into a struct. But i never really care about making error codes unique for each function which is what your approach seems to be about.

Again, this is my specific, but i never really felt the need to do otherwise. Error codes defined for the whole module usually fit to be passed between procedures that implement this module. Now what if your approach could actually be mapped on a module boundary instead of the function? :)

Comment: The OP has -1 as an error code from two different routines ... you don't seem to have understood the code or its intent at all.

Comment: @JimBalter: I think Inso undestood it fine.  I think by "making error codes unique for each function" that Inso meant "making error codes specific for each function".

Comment: When I was writing this I did have that nagging thought in the back of my mind that "yeah, maybe this is pretty pointless", but I do think there is at least a little value taking this appraoch. You're right though: there would need to be a way pass these errors up and down a call stack, which would require some more code or significant idiomatic changes, which may or may not be worth that overhead...

Comment: @JimBalter Clearly it's not clear to me.  How can you so matter-of-factly know what Inso intended?

Comment: @jamesdlin Because I read and understood it. And earlier your wrote "I think Inso undestood it fine" but now write "Clearly it's not clear to me". I detect a strong whiff of something unpleasant. Over and out.

Comment: @JimBalter: But I read it, and I understood it too. By "Clearly it's not clear to me", I meant that it's not clear to me that I'm wrong (which is what you asserted).  Inso's post is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: The odor grows stronger: "How can you so matter-of-factly know what Inso intended?" + "Inso's post is perfectly clear to me"